# IntelliJ IDEA -GIT Benefits?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

What are the benefits of integrating GIT into the console of IntelliJ IDEA for Windows?

I have done it and honestly I cannot see in which way I can save some time while developing. Are there some commands that will help to a faster development? 
Thanks.

Comment: Your question invites opinion, so I won't give a formal answer, but one way in which the plugin can massively help is the Git conflict and diff tools.  It is very convenient to be able to see a diff of a source file against e.g. another branch directly inside IntelliJ.  For the other operations, I personally prefer using the bash, although you can do them from IntelliJ, perhaps a bit faster.

Comment: What do you mean by "integrating Git into the console"? The Git integration in IntelliJ IDEA does not work through the console, it uses many dedicated UI elements (Changes toolwindow etc.). You can invoke Git from the terminal inside IntelliJ IDEA, but there's no integration, it works exactly the same as invoking Git in a normal terminal.